# Changing the data source of ui select on event

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I want to change the data source of this select each time I select something new.

This is how the markup of the directive looks:

```
<ui-select on-select="fClick($item,$model)" 
    on-remove="rClick($item,$model)"
    reset-search-input="true" 
    close-on-select="true" 
    multiple 
    ng-model="namesModel.selected"
    theme="select2" 
    ng-disabled="disabled" 
    style="width: 100%;">

    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select user...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="user in users">
        <div ng-bind-html="user.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

For example:
My initial source is something like: `scope.users = [{name:"user1",address:"address1"},{name:"user2",address:"address2"}]` whenever I select user1 I want to call a rest service and change the value of `scope.users` or change the whole source if possible.

The issue is that on `fClick` i do something like this:

```
'SomeSvc.getNewDataSource().then(function (data) { scope.users = data; })'
```

but it doesn't change the source. What am i missing here?

Comment: Is it the same scope instance? Try inspecting your model with ng-inspector or batarang extension for the browser.

Comment: The other problem is if you are doing something outside of the digest, maybe in a jQuery handler and not calling $apply